# Como calcular o tempo de download de um website usando wget?

Tags: bash, wget

Estou trabalhando em um projeto onde eu preciso calcular o tempo de carregamento de uma webpage para fins de otimização.

Estou usando este comando:

> $ time wget -H -p --delete-after melga.com.br 2&> /dev/null

Mas não tenho certeza se o tempo de acesso no disco está interferindo na medição.

Caso possua uma forma mais eficiente de calcular também ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando o `curl`:

```
$ curl -so /dev/null -w '%{time_total} segs\n' http://melga.com.br/
```

Usando o `time` e `wget`:

```
$ time wget -q -o /dev/null http://melga.com.br/
```

Espero que ajude!